# positioning elements within a listview row

Tags: android

this is the layout used in my SimpleAdapter. the correct title is populated, the height is correctly set, but the textview appears on the top left of the row instead of the bottom left. how can i fix that?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dip"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you plan to add some more Views into this ListView item, then, you could start with RelativeLayout because it gives you much more freedom. If you will keep it simple, then, keep LinearLayout and user gravity attributes to align elements properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change LinearLayout to RealativeLayout. It should workk as expected.

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

are RelativeLayout attributes.

Answer (score 1):

`android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft` are used with a `RelativeLayout`.

With a `LinearLayout` you should use `android:gravity` on a parent view, or `android:layout_gravity` on a child view.

Your layout should look like the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dip"
    android:gravity="start|bottom"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</LinearLayout>
```